# MySQL Query: How to join and group and I don't know what they're called

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to MySQL and have tried to teach myself how to use it so sorry if I'm not using the right terminology...

I have 2 tables: Students and Payments
The Payments table has a Student ID, Amount and Type (either Bond, Installment or Repair)

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to get a column for the sum of all bond payments and another for the sum of all instalment payments for each student and showing all the students that have a payment or not.

Alternatively, if you know any good guides for free (my budget is $0) that can help, that would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. You will want to use SUM(Amount) and group by student id and type.

Comment: There are lots of sql tutorials in the net. You can use 'Join' statements and 'sum()' function to get what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want all `students`, even if they don't have any matches in `payments`, you must use a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
select students.*, payments.type, SUM(payments.amount)
from students
left join payments on payments.student_id = students.id
group by students.id, payments.type
```

Note that this puts the different payment types each on their own row. Turning them into columns in the result is called *pivoting*. Some database systems have built-in ways to do this, but MySQL doesn't. Doing it requires knowing all the possible values of `payments.type`.

```
select students.*,
        SUM(IF(payments.type = 'Bond', payments.amount, 0)) Bond,
        SUM(IF(payments.type = 'Installment', payments.amount, 0)) Installment,
        SUM(IF(payments.type = 'Repair', payments.amount, 0)) Repair
from students
left join payments on payments.student_id = students.id
group by students.id
```

Comment: Perfect! except you have one too many closing brackets on each line which drove me up the wall for a few hours...

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you the query how you can get sum of all bond payments and installment payments.

```
Select student_id , sum(amount),Type from payments group by student_id,Type
```

To learn about the Mysql please refer the following sites.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/

Comment: And please avoid linking to w3fools, they already have google fooled, no need to help them with their SEO.

Comment: @Barmar : Whats the problem if I give link of good sql tutorial sites. Helping someone in stackoverflow is not bad. When I was a student I learn from this sites. How comes the question of SEO. Are you here only for giving negetive comments?